# Converting the time in IST to EST using ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert the time which is in IST to EST using Ruby(NOT Rails). I tried different ways. But its returning the time in UTC. here is the example.
 08/08/2014 01:45 AM

Is there any way to convert the above date into EST.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
require 'time'

ist = Time.parse('08/08/2014 01:45 AM +05:30')
p ist
est = ist.getlocal("-05:00")
p est
```

**Output**

```
2014-08-08 01:45:00 +0530
2014-08-07 15:15:00 -0500
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would check out a couple methods in the Time class in ruby's documentation http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Time.html#method-i-2B
Specifically `Time#now` `Time#strftime` `Time#-`

To start off I am going to assume that you are in Indian Standard Time and would like to know what time it is for your friend in Eastern Standard Time. According to google.com.. IST is 9 and 1/2 hours ahead of EST. Which means you need to get your current time in IST and subtract 9.5 hours. See if this is what your looking for..

```
#Simple Method That Takes a Time Argument
#If you read correctly, Time#- uses seconds. 
def to_est(ist)
  (ist - 34200).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p")
end

#Calling the method
puts to_est(Time.now)
```

`%m` = Month

`%d` = Day

`%Y` = Year

`%I` = Hour

`%M` = Minute

`%p` = Meridian Indicator